# Calculating 3d polygons' surface area using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, polygon, arcgis-10.3, area, 3d-analyst

I've got a polygon feature class with Z values enabled. The polygon entities represent billboards. I'm looking for a way to measure the front surface area of this entities - i.e the area of the billboards from one side.

Can I do this using a Geoprocessing tool?

**Some snapshots**

[image]

Polygon in ArcMap

[image]

Polygon in ArcScene

Comment: Have you tried using trigonometry in Python?  If so, please edit the question to contain your Python code.

Comment: How do they look like on a map? Just line?

Comment: So they are triangles?

Comment: This might help: 1) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TIKkVdHsk9I 2) http://www.giscourse.com/calculating-the-volume-of-a-surface-using-arcgis/

Comment: what do you call "front" in your description ? the nearly vertical side or the nearly horizontal one?

Comment: -1 for no feedback on multiple questions above.

Comment: Sorry all commentators for the long response. I'll write to each comment separately. 

1. I have not tried yet to use trigonometry in python 
2.  They look as snapshoted above
3. they are not triangles but an array of xyz nodes that compose a simple (non self intersecting) polygon. arcmap shows them as triangles.
4. the youtube link isn't helping because i need to find the area of discrete polygons. i.e. non-continuous TIN
5. In most cases - yes. But there are some billboards that aren't vertical but curvy (or any other shape).

Comment: The answer, I think, lies in this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12642256/python-find-area-of-polygon-from-xyz-coordinates

which points to this one:
http://geomalgorithms.com/a01-_area.html#3D%20Polygons

I'll need to dig a bit further to see. thank yo all for your comments so far

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, copy and paste the defs in [the accepted answer of the post that you mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12642256/python-find-area-of-polygon-from-xyz-coordinates) to the python interpreter of ArcMap. And then run a cursor on the shapes to calculate the 3D area, such as:

```
for row in arcpy.SearchCursor("Billboard Layer on My Table of Content"):
    area_array=[[j.X,j.Y,j.Z] for i in row.Shape.getPart() for j in i]
    print row.OBJECTID, area(area_array)
```

This routine just prints the ID and the area of the feature but it can be used to record areas into a new field as well by `UpdateCursor`. Intentionally, I have exemplified the old cursor approach, otherwise there are much more efficient utilities in arcpy's `data access` module (i.e., `arcpy.da`)

Answer (score 1):

If you have 3D Analyst, this works - **for individual polygons**:

1. [Create a TIN](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/3d-analyst-toolbox/create-tin.htm) using  your polygon
2. Use [Add Surface Information](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/3d-analyst-toolbox/add-surface-information.htm) with your polygon as input feature class and the corresponding TIN as input surface. Check "SURFACE_AREA" as output property.

The 3D area is then added in a new field to your polygon feature class' attribute table.

You can automate this with Python or ModelBuilder if you have a large number of polygons or need to repeat the process.