# Calculating 3D surface area base on slope in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, 3d-analyst, slope, watershed, upstream

How can I calculate 3D surface area base on slope in GIS for each morphological units in watershed?

Answer (score 2):

> You will need 3D analyst
>
> Create a TIN using your polygon
>
> - Add Surface Information with your polygon as input feature class and the corresponding TIN as input surface.
>
>   - Check "SURFACE_AREA" box as output property.
>
> The 3D area is then added in a new field to your polygon feature class' attribute table.

This post provides the steps [Calculating 3d polygons' surface area using ArcGIS for Desktop?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/203338/calculating-3d-polygons-surface-area-using-arcgis-for-desktop)