# Correcting forestry acreages due to slope to get actual acreages treated

Tags: arcgis-desktop, slope

I came up with a process to get actual acreages vs map acres of steep slopes, but I am wondering what others do to correct for steep slopes and get actual acreage treated? For mine, In ArcGIS Desktop, I use a DEM to create a percent slope raster. After classifying the slope data, I use our treatment polygons to cut out the slope data so I know how many acres I have at a particular slope. Then I use a table found in a range management book that tells you what percentage to increase the acreage by per slope percent. It works well, I'm just wondering if there is a better more efficient process or tool I could be using?

Comment: Isn't that just basic trigonometry?

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/258037/calculate-3d-surface-area-base-on-slope-in-gis

Comment: Compute raster using 1/cos(slope). Average of this times polygon area is your answer.