# Getting Surface Area on 3D Objects (ArcGIS Pro)

Tags: arcgis-pro, 3d, 3d-model, 3d-map

TLDR: I have a 3D multipatch feature class and need the surface area of the facade of the building.

I brought in some data from Revit into ArcGIS Pro, processed it (project it, georef), converted the data into a GDB feature class (Layer 3D to Feature Class). I used the Add Z Information tool to add the surface area of each 3D object, which is close to what I want, but not quite. I also tried field calculating geometry, using area and sq. ft as the unit type, but it only accurately captures geometries that are horizontal.

As (hopefully) shown in the screenshot, the surface area will calculate the facade plus the interior surface area, and the surface area of the 3D object wall thickness. Does anyone know of a way to just get the facade area? I've been banging my head against the wall on this one.

[image]
I have also seen this answer in StackExchange but I think this will just give me the same result as the surface area from Add Z Information.
 [Calculating 3d polygons' surface area using ArcGIS Desktop?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/203338/calculating-3d-polygons-surface-area-using-arcgis-desktop)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Exploding a multipatch feature](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/help/editing/explode-a-multipatch-feature.htm) and then running [Add Z Information](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/3d-analyst/add-z-information.htm) got the correct surface area for the facade.